# Private network configuration for Xen guest operation systems

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, xen

I've been working around with Xen. I managed to bring up 2 virtual machines; 1: Windows Server 2008, 2: Ubuntu desktop 12.04 LTS.
Here is my question. I created a bridge called sw0(up and running) using brctl tool for those two virtual machines to have them communicate privately.
I'm posting the networking configuration part of both virtual environments:
Windows Server:

```
vif: ['mac:00:16:3e:0c:07:98, bridge=xenbr0', 'mac=83:f9:2d:6b:09:ec, bridge=sw0']
```

Ubuntu 12.04:

```
vif: ['mac=9e:b2:4f:5b:35:79, bridge=sw0']
```

At this point Xen should handle a bridged connection between these two machines.
The network configuration within the windows and ubuntu machines are as below:

Windows Server:

```
Address: 10.0.0.1/24
```

-I added a persistent route in there letting the windows machine know where to route the packets.

-I turned the firewall off inside the windows machine just in case if it blocks connection inbound/outbound.

Ubuntu 12.04:

```
address: 10.0.1.1/24
```

The problem is pinging from the windows machine should reply back that it sees the ubuntu machine in there. But I'm getting timedout reply instead.

One more thing to add: The windows machine is able to see the outside world which is the internet using xenbr0.

tcpdump within the host operating system(xenhost) on sw0 shows that ubuntu is sending out icmp packets looking for the windows machine, but for some reason the windows machine is not replying!
I'm not sure if I was wrong understanding the xen's network layout or what?!
Any help?

Comment: These two machines are on a bridge, so the same layer 2 network, and yet the two ips are on different layer 3 networks.  You'll want to put both addresses in the same IP network or you'll need to route between them.  Or am I missing something?  Change the Ubuntu box to 10.0.0.2/24.

Comment: Thank Paul, I'm still getting the same not reply from ubuntu box. Immonna post the routing of both machines as an answer below.

Comment: Please don't post answers that aren't answers.  [edit] your question to add additional information.

Comment: Once you have the ip addresses right, could you add the results of `tcpdump -i eth0 -e host 10.0.0.1 and host 10.0.0.2`

Comment: The thing is tcpdump shouldn't be listening on eth0. what I know that it should listen on sw0. right?

Comment: You didn't include the interface names presented on ubuntu in your question.  Given that ubuntu only has a single interface, I assumed it would be eth0.  Please add `ifconfig -a` from the ubuntu box to the question.

Comment: oW yeah! within the ubuntu box there's only eth0! I ran tcpdump on xen machine(ubuntu again) to sniff what happens on the link between two machines.

Comment: Well this is so weird! tcpdump within the ubuntu box shows nothing on eth0. but ping request on windows box reply back. OMG! what's going on here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14178/discussion-between-mehdix-and-paul)